# Xamarin Android 5.1.1, Leaflet, Mapbox not working in webview

Tags: javascript, android, xamarin, leaflet, mapbox

I have created an app that supports all `Android 5.1.1`, `Android 9` and `Android 10` rugged tablets. The application is built in `Xamarin Android native` (not Xamarin Forms). The application uses Leaflet to show maps in a Webview. A custom maps server feeds map tiles to `Leaftlet`.

Now bosses want to replace the custom maps server with `Mapbox`. Means, now Mapbox should feed map tiles to Leaflet. I have successfully got it working on `Android 9`, and `Android 10` (in Xamarin Android, Leaflet, Webview). But maps do not show up on `Android 5.1.1` at all. My Mapbox initialization code is as below:

```
var mapboxTiles = L.tileLayer(
      `https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/mapbox/streets-v11/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=<my_token>`,
{
  attribution: '© <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/feedback/">Mapbox</a>',
  tileSize: 512,
  zoomOffset: -1,
});


map.addLayer(mapboxTiles);
```

This same piece of code works well on `Android 9`, and `Android 10`. But it does not work at Android 5.1.1. I have debugged WebView using Chrome (chrome://inspect) and in case of `Android 5.1.1` the JavaScript file (in which I have written the above code) does not even load at all. I want that MapBox should work on Android 5.1.1 also.

Any help or guidance would be appreciated. Thanks guys.

Comment: have you checked if Mapbox supports Android 5?  That OS is 7 years old and is no longer supported

Comment: @Jason thanks for replying. I couldn't find this compatibility information anywhere. Mapbox do not provide any sdk for Xamarin Android, hence I was using Leaflet. But I couldnt any information that is Mapbox supported on Leaflet on Xamarin Android? Thanks.

Comment: I have no idea.  Questions about support should be directed to those companies, not SO.

Comment: @Jason I am asking on SO to see if anyone else has faced this sort of problem, and how they have fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: can we use leaflet map kit for uwp using xamarin.forms?